# Save MySQL results to an array and merge

Tags: php

I have this code which permits me to save (i guess so) the mysql results into an array, i get then, two arrays and i need to merge them into one!

The problem is apparently it won't merge in the correct way, it merges but not all values..

What am i doing wrong here?
Thanks!

```
<?php 
$date1=mysql_query("SELECT date FROM date WHERE att_id='$att_id'");
$date2=mysql_query("SELECT date FROM date_pdv WHERE att_id='$att_id'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($date1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf("Data: %s", $row["date"]);
    $firstdate=$row['date'];
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($date2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf(" Data1: %s", $row["date"]);
    $seconddate=$row['date'];
}
$result = array_merge((array)$firstdate, (array)$seconddate);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Type casting does not convert a string to a array, you actually have to pass (and build) arrays:

```
$date1=mysql_query("SELECT date FROM date WHERE att_id='$att_id'");
$date2=mysql_query("SELECT date FROM date_pdv WHERE att_id='$att_id'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($date1, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf("Data: %s", $row["date"]);
    $firstdate[] =$row['date'];
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($date2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    printf(" Data1: %s", $row["date"]);
    $seconddate[] =$row['date'];
}
$result = array_merge($firstdate, $seconddate);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is right :)
I'm accepting your answer in a few minutes!

Answer (score 0):

```
$firstdate[]=$row['date'];
$seconddate[]=$row['date'];
```

your firstdate and seconddate are not array put above lines in respective place and you will get the solution... and stop using mysql functions use pdo

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a single query for that?

```
(SELECT date 
FROM date
WHERE att_id='$att_id')
UNION 
(SELECT date
FROM date_pdv
WHERE att_id='$att_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to merge 2 arrays if you got 2 arrays.
But, you don't you have 2 strings..

so

```
$result = array();
array_push($result, $row['date'];

var_dump( $result );
```